# How to bind html into Angular 2.0

Tags: angular, ng-bind-html

In angular 1 binding works like ng-bind-html="htmlValue"

How to bind html in Angular 2.0

Comment: ng-bind-html would sanitize everything to prevent script injection attacks. the solution bellow I think does not do that, but haven't tried it.

Comment: Yes, you're right! I made a test with `<em onmouseover="this.textContent='PWN3D!'">click here</em>` and the JavaScript code is actually executed on the click...

Answer (score 48):

I think that you could use the `innerHtml` attribute and bind something on it:

```xml
<span [innerHtml]="someHtmlContent"></span>
```

Here is a sample:

```typescript
@Component({
  selector: 'first-app',
  template: `
    <span [innerHtml]="value"></span>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private http:Http) {
    this.value = '<strong>test</strong>';
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks @thierry 
its working

Comment: what if I need to use another component inside `[innerHtml]`, like this, which is not working `<span [innerHtml]="<a [routerLink]="/test"></a>"></span>`
This router link is not getting compiled.

Comment: @Wishnu Though it's a bit late: in that case you can get away with an `*ngIf` on the `a` instead of an `[innerHtml]`.